# Regular expression for 12;1;19-39;43

Tags: php, regex

I am new to regular expression and trying to match the following pattern using regular expression:

1. Groups of numbers, each looks like either a single number like 12, or a number range like 19-39
2. Groups are separated by semicolon(;)
3. All numbers are within range 1-48 (but we don't need to verify this in regular expression)

So an example match would be 12;13;19-39;43

For a single group, I can think of using

```
\b[1-9]{1}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1}\b
```

for single number, and

```
\b[1-9]{1}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1}-[1-9]{1}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1}\b
```

for number range.

The question is how to take the semicolon(;) into consideration also: any number of the above groups of number(s) connected by ; can be matched.

Comment: Trust me, others would give you an answer here, but I believe you need to practice RegEx to become perfect. Have a look at [This Resource](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/). It will solve most of your regex problems :)

Comment: @SunnyRGupta Better to suggest http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: Well suggestions vary according to preference :)

Answer (score 1):

This should exactly match your requirement:

`\d*[0-9](|-\d*[0-9]|;\d*[0-9])*$`

**Explanation:**

1. Match any digit multiple times.
2. Next, check for a `-` or `;` followed by another series of digits.

Repeat this till matches are found.

Try it out here:

http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

You can paste sample text in the big text area and see the exp in action. Cheers!

Comment: Additional tip: you can use the "Share Link" button on the right to make direct examples so that there's no need to copy+paste. http://regexr.com?365mn

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
/^\d*[0-9](|.\d*[0-9]|;\d*[0-9])*$/;
```

Its matches your requirement.

Comment: This will pass `12;13;19$39;43` and `12;13;19:39;43`

Comment: @ Sunny R yes, because here I have used **.(dot)** for global matching. This is a generic regX. you are free to customize it according to your requirement :)

Answer (score 0):

One trick to learning these is to try and break it into parts and write brutal ones to start:

1. 1-48 alone ending in ; you can be as complicated as: `((\d)|([1-3]\d)|(4[0-8]));`
2. for dashed groups just the same components repeated with a dash: `((\d)|([1-3]\d)|(4[0-8]))-((\d)|([1-3]\d)|(4[0-8]));`
3. Now Combine to get either / or and repeat the whole group: `((((\d)|([1-3]\d)|(4[0-8]));)|(((\d)|([1-3]\d)|(4[0-8]))-((\d)|([1-3]\d)|(4[0-8]));))*`

Now we have this gross, brute force, regex with a ridiculous number of groupings above, but it works. Next we can think about simplifying and you have an even better place (sort of) to start asking for help from.

Was going to start simplifying, but you have a other answers here already.

Simplifying a little and just noting your final number does not end with a semicolon you can start with merging with something like @Sunny has:

```
^((\d)|([1-3]\d)|(4[0-8]))(|-((\d)|([1-3]\d)|(4[0-8]))|;((\d)|([1-3]\d)|(4[0-8])))*$
```

Comment: Updated to note no end semicolon